# using a dictionary function to call a df column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has a list of all of the df column names and maps them to function names.

```
import pandas as pd
 
data= [["john","","","English","","","","","","","","",""]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'Communication_Language__c', 'country', 'company', 'email', 'industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'customerSegment', 'Existing_Customer__c', 'GDPR_Email_Permission__c'])
filename= 'Template'
 
lang_trans= {"English":"ENG", "French":"FR"}

def lang (lang_trans,df):
    df.replace(lang_trans, inplace=True)
    df.str.upper()
    return df

parsing_map{
"Communication_Language__c": lang}
```

I would like to replace the data in the df with the abbreviation for 'english' as 'ENG',
I have tried to achieve this with

```
def lang (lang_trans,df):
    df.replace(lang_trans, inplace=True)
    df.str.upper()
    return df
```

but  it is not transforming 'english' to 'ENG' in the df

How would I call the function lang from the dictionary to change the value in the `df[Communication_language_c` to be 'ENG'

desired output

```
data= [["john","","","ENG","","","","","","","","",""]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'Communication_Language__c
```

Comment: shouldn't you replace lang with df in: lang.replace(lang_trans, inplace=True)
    lang.str.upper()

Comment: when i change to `df.replace(lang_trans, inplace=True)` it still stay the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
 
data= [["john","","","English","","","","","","","","",""]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'Communication_Language__c', 'country', 'company', 'email', 'industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'customerSegment', 'Existing_Customer__c', 'GDPR_Email_Permission__c'])

filename= 'Template'

 
lang_trans= {"English":"ENG", "French":"FR"}

def update_lang(df_temp, column, lang_dict):
    for k, v in lang_dict.items():
        df_temp[column] = df[column].replace(k,v)
    
    return df_temp

df = update_lang(df, 'Communication_Language__c', lang_trans)
print(df)
```

Comment: This worked, do you always have to do `df=update_lang(df, 'communication_lang_c', lang_trans)` or is there a way to do this without referencing the column name?

Comment: If you just want to replace all references to "English" etc within the entire dataframe regardless of which column it is in, then you can just search the entire dataframe. i.e. `df_temp = df_temp.replace(k,v)`   and then you can take out the `column` parameter in the `update_lang` function, and modify the call to that function accordingly

Comment: I guess you could also define the column explicitly within the function if you do not want to have the flexibility of choosing which column to search.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a function is not necessary. I also don't understand why you are using the line "lang.str.upper()" if you just want to transform "English" to "ENG" and "French" to "FR" so I took it out. Does this get the output you want?

```
import pandas as pd

data = [["john", "", "", "English", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,
                  columns=['firstName', 'lastName', 'state', 'Communication_Language__c', 'country', 'company', 'email',
                           'industry', 'System_Type__c', 'AccountType', 'customerSegment', 'Existing_Customer__c',
                           'GDPR_Email_Permission__c'])
filename = 'Template'
lang_trans = {"English": "ENG", "French": "FR"}
df['Communication_Language__c'].replace(lang_trans, inplace=True)
```

Comment: this would not be what I would be looking for since I am wanting to use the function reference found in the dictionary instead of referencing the column directly.